# The -a argument to Flask?

Tags: python, flask, import, python-import, importerror

I'm reading the [Quickstart](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#what-to-do-if-the-server-does-not-start) part of Flask's official tutorial:

> **Invalid Import Name**
>
> The `-a` argument to **flask** is the name of the module to import. In
>   case that module is incorrectly named you will get an import error
>   upon start (or if debug is enabled when you navigate to the
>   application). It will tell you what it tried to import and why it
>   failed.
>
> The most common reason is a typo or because you did not actually
>   create an `app` object.

It mentioned "the `-a` argument to flask", but I cannot see anything about `-a` in the rest of this document. Also, `flask run -a foo.py` gives me `Error: no such option: -a`.

My question is: How can I use the `-a` argument to specify the module to be run by flask?

Comment: It looks like a documentation error to me. I think `FLASK_APP=foo.py flask run` is the only way to specify the module via the CLI.

Comment: https://github.com/pallets/flask/commit/523e27118359425048541d92892f20ee048c0b76 seems to be where that was removed.

Comment: @smarx Got it. Also, the output of `flask --help` contains "(**either** through the FLASK_APP
  environment variable)". The ", or ..." part is missing!

Answer (score 1):

Your link is from [0.11 version](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/quickstart/#what-to-do-if-the-server-does-not-start). But if you go to this [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#what-to-do-if-the-server-does-not-start) (which is 0.12 version of flask), it is missing. [This](https://github.com/pallets/flask/commit/523e27118359425048541d92892f20ee048c0b76) commit should justify the reason it is not available :)